# How to debug DHCP timeout on WiFi connect?

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, dhcp, netctl

I've recently moved to a place with public WiFi (so I don't have access to the router or their DHCP config), and am running into issues connecting with my Arch laptop.

I've tried using both NetworkManager and netctl to connect, but both fail at getting a DHCP lease. It should be noted that every other device (Android and iOS phones, Windows and macOS laptops) does so without problems.

How do I go about debugging this? Am I missing a package, or am I connecting wrongly?

---

#### NetworkManager

I use `nmcli` to connect:

```
$ nmcli dev wifi

*  SSID            MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY 
   ssidOfWifi      Infra  1     54 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA2     
   ssidOfWifi      Infra  13    54 Mbit/s  34      ▂▄__  WPA2     
   ssidOfWifi      Infra  13    54 Mbit/s  22      ▂___  WPA2     

$ nmcli dev wifi connect ssidOfWifi password passwordToWifi

Error: Connection activation failed: (5) IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.).

$ systemctl status NetworkManager

...
Jan 09 17:49:43 home NetworkManager[5621]: <info>  [1483980583.9385] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'ssidOfWifi'.
Jan 09 17:49:43 home NetworkManager[5621]: <info>  [1483980583.9386] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jan 09 17:49:43 home NetworkManager[5621]: <info>  [1483980583.9390] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jan 09 17:50:29 home NetworkManager[5621]: <info>  [1483980629.0055] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed unknown -> timeout
Jan 09 17:50:29 home NetworkManager[5621]: <info>  [1483980629.0214] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Jan 09 17:50:29 home NetworkManager[5621]: <info>  [1483980629.0215] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed timeout -> done
Jan 09 17:50:29 home NetworkManager[5621]: <info>  [1483980629.0220] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Jan 09 17:50:29 home NetworkManager[5621]: <info>  [1483980629.0223] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jan 09 17:50:29 home NetworkManager[5621]: <warn>  [1483980629.0233] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'ssidOfWifi'
Jan 09 17:50:29 home NetworkManager[5621]: <info>  [1483980629.0319] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jan 09 17:50:29 home NetworkManager[5621]: <info>  [1483980629.0421] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF (scanning)
Jan 09 17:50:29 home NetworkManager[5621]: <warn>  [1483980629.0453] sup-iface[0x1d5ec00,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Jan 09 17:50:29 home NetworkManager[5621]: <info>  [1483980629.0454] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
```

#### Netctl

I use `wifi-menu -o` to connect. This shows only one "ssidOfWifi", unlike `nmcli` which shows one for each accesspoint.

```
$ sudo wifi-menu -o

Job for netctl@wlp2s0\x2dssidOfWifi.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status "netctl@wlp2s0\\x2dssidOfNetwork.service"" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

$ journalctl -xe

...
Jan 09 23:10:34 home dhcpcd[14402]: wlp2s0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Jan 09 23:11:03 home dhcpcd[14402]: timed out
Jan 09 23:11:03 home dhcpcd[14402]: dhcpcd exited
Jan 09 23:11:03 home network[14363]: DHCP IPv4 lease attempt failed on interface 'wlp2s0'
Jan 09 23:11:03 home kernel: wlp2s0: deauthenticating from AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Jan 09 23:11:03 home network[14363]: Failed to bring the network up for profile 'wlp2s0-ssidOfWifi'
Jan 09 23:11:03 home systemd[1]: netctl@wlp2s0\x2dssidOfWifi.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Comment: I have the same issue on my guest wifi. Manually connecting with wpa_suplicant and dhcpcd works; not the other method. When i look at wireshark dump, I don't see the DHCPOFFER from the pc/laptop coming from;

Answer (score 0):

If it's a timeout, it's probably on their end. Check with management to see if they have any special requirements in order to connect.